# `torch.nn.module` forward pass with a non batched output

Tags: python, pytorch, batch-processing

I'd like a Pytorch net to take in as its forward pass some batched input and non batch input. I was wondering if there was an aesthetic way of doing this ?

```py
Model(nn.Module):
   ...

def forward(self, t : float, y : Tensor) -> Tensor :
    ...
```

I was wondering if it were possible to have the `forward` method take as input the batched data `y` of shape `[batch, ...]` and the scalar `t`. Is there any way of doing this apart from broadcasting t to the shape `[batch, 1]` ?

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible to feed both scalar and batched data into the `forward` function in PyTorch. The former automatically scales to the dimension of the latter by way of broadcasting in PyTorch.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(20, 20)

    def forward(self, t: float, y: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        y = self.fc(y)
        y = F.relu(y)
        y = t * y 
        return y

model = Model()
y = torch.randn((10, 20))  # batch of size 10
t = 0.5  # scalar

output = model(t, y)
```